# How to start camera preview in 240 fps range in android using CameraX?

Tags: android, frame-rate, android-camera2, android-camerax, slowmotion

I want to start my camera preview in 240 fps only. I am able to start the preview using CameraX android jetpack library but it is giving me 30 fps. I want to get 240 fps when I open my camera.

Answer (score 0):

Please understand that CameraX library is a convenience wrapper for camera2 API. The purpose of this library is ease of use in typical scenarios, not going beyond them. You should work directly with the underlying API to achieve your goal.

Note that many devices have 30 FPS as maximum, even for lowest resolution.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will check for Camera2 API